# How to get rid of useless columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As you seen iny my code below, I only need the column `.col-md-8` but I am using the both `.col-md-2` classes to center my content. Although it works well, I am just looking for a cleaner way. So is there a way I could get rid of those `col-md-2` classes?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        MY CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

I have also tried using `col-md-offset-2`. This way I can get rid of the first `.col-md-2` but it is not giving me the `.col-md-8` that I am needing.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        MY CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

So the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `margin: 0 auto`?

Comment: _“but it is not giving me the .col-md-8 that I am needing”_ – well if you write `col-md-10` in your code, then you can’t expect to get an _8_ columns wide element ... so far, so obvious.

Comment: Quite an eccentric question. Waht's the problem with the default behaviour. I mean bootstrap is designed that way and if you still want to change things, then don't expect it to be cleaner as there will be tweaks in css as well as your html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use offsets, for example:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    MY CONTENT
</div>
```

It should work, I think in your example the problem is that you're using `col-md-10` and not `col-md-8`. You can ignore the space after the content, as long as you have your columns inside a `.row`.

Comment: What is the difference with a `[col-md-2 (void)]` `[col-md-8 (content)]` `[col-md-2 (void)]`? :)

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I would like to understand the difference between the code you provided, and an approch where you "center" the content between two `col-md-2`.

Comment: The difference is how clean the markup is. By using the col-md-2 approach, you add useless empty tags to your HTML. It makes the file bigger, less readable, more error prone, that's why the guys from twitter added the offset classes into bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Jonas

Comment: Thank you. I guess I just didn't know how to use the offset but now it is clear to me.